# Send Email After Signup Using Laravel 5.8 From Localhost

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending an email from the localhost to the user after signup using SMTP. But it gives this message in response **Expected response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication required\r\n\"**. Please tell me why is it and how do I resolve this issue??

**.evn file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword@12345
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**controller file mail code**

```
    //Send Email

    $email = $input['email'];
    $messageData = ['email' =>$input['email'],'name' =>$input['name']];
    Mail::send('emails.mail',$messageData,function($message) use($email){
        $message->to($email)->subject('Registration with AddSpy');
    });
```

**mail.php**

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'offers.addspy@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Add Spy'),
],
```

**Response I Get**

```
{
"message": "Expected response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication required\r\n\"",
"exception": "Swift_TransportException",
"file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
"line": 457,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
        "line": 341,
        "function": "assertResponseCode",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\EsmtpTransport.php",
        "line": 305,
        "function": "executeCommand",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
        "line": 390,
        "function": "executeCommand",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
        "line": 497,
        "function": "doDataCommand",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
        "line": 516,
        "function": "doMailTransaction",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
        "line": 206,
        "function": "sendTo",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mailer.php",
        "line": 71,
        "function": "send",
        "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php",
        "line": 484,
        "function": "send",
        "class": "Swift_Mailer",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php",
        "line": 259,
        "function": "sendSwiftMessage",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php",
        "line": 239,
        "function": "send",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\razorpay\\PaymentController.php",
        "line": 59,
        "function": "__callStatic",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
        "type": "::"
    },
    {
        "function": "pay_success",
        "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\razorpay\\PaymentController",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php",
        "line": 54,
        "function": "call_user_func_array"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php",
        "line": 45,
        "function": "callAction",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
        "line": 219,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
        "line": 176,
        "function": "runController",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 680,
        "function": "run",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 30,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php",
        "line": 75,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
        "line": 37,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
        "line": 66,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
        "line": 41,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
        "line": 49,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
        "line": 56,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 104,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 682,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 657,
        "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 623,
        "function": "runRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 612,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
        "line": 176,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 30,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
        "line": 62,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 163,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 104,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
        "line": 151,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
        "line": 116,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\public\\index.php",
        "line": 55,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\server.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "require_once"
    }
]
```

}

Please help let me know where I'm wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope those weren't your real mail / password credentials in your question, otherwise you should change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the mail driver is already set to `smtp`. Run `php artisan config:cache` and try again.